# tabbarcontroller and facebook api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm trying to implement Facebook API in my app code.
Pratically i have a simple TabbarController with 2 ViewController.

My AppDelegate code:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
   UIWindow *window;
   UITabBarController *tabBarController;
   Facebook *facebook;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) Facebook *facebook;
```

method code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"12345678910" andDelegate:_tabBarController];
  ............

return YES;
}
```

FirstViewController.h

```
#import "Facebook.h"
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FBRequestDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {
}
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "Appdelegate.h"

-(IBAction)shareFacebook {
   AppDelegate *appdelegate  = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   if (![appdelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream", 
                            @"read_stream",
                            nil];
    [appdelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];
   }
 }
```

I received a warning for this code: **"andDelegate:_tabBarController"**
Sending "UITabBarController *" to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Comment: Sending "UITabBarController *" to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FBSessionDelegate>'

Comment: FBSessionDelegate is used in FirstViewController.h, not needed to AppDelegate.h

Answer (score 0):

i would say UITabBarController * is not an FBSessionDelegate ... add the protocol as `<UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate,FBSessionDelegate >` and then

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"12345678910" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: FBSessionDelegate is yet declared in FirstViewController.h, not needed to AppDelegate.h

Comment: then you should pass a FirstViewController not a TabBarController

Answer (score 0):

In my app I declare and initialize the facebook object in the AppDelegate just like you. However, I made the AppDelegate use these (just like the other answer said it) : FBRequestDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate. After that I placed all the facebook login/logout/post..etc methods in app delegate class.

After that you can just pass the facebook object to your FirstViewController from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

If you dont understand let me know I'll give you more details. I might not explain it very well.

PS: i might be wrong with this but from what i've seen around the web it is easier to declare methods at the beginning in the app delagete didfinishlaunchingwithoptions and then pass them to specific view controllers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have multiple ViewController with "Share FB button". I must insert all method facebook in Appdelegate ? And how retrieve the method in my views controller?

Comment: YEs you put everything in the AppDelegate if you want and then you pass the facebook object to your view controller(s) of choice like this in your didFInishLaunchingWithOptions:
`code`
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"put your app id here" andDelegate:self];

 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
FirstViewController *first = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

first.myFacebookPointer = facebook;
`code`
Of course in FirstViewController create a facebook property to which  you will do the assignment.

Comment: `facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"put your app id here" andDelegate:self]; 
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController; 
FirstViewController *first = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]; 
first.myFacebookPointer = facebook;`